# Hot to set port number for Azure Kubernetes Dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am trying to spawn the Azure Kubernetes Dashboard, using the indications found in the azure AKS
"View Kubernetes Dashboard".

In particular I get

```
az aks browse --resource-group my-resource-group --name aks-name-westeurope-001
```

By default it spawns a port redirection to port 8001, that unfortunately is already used, so I get

```
F0716 12:08:13.743013   11860 proxy.go:160] listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8001: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

How can I change the port so that I can login to my kubernetes dashboard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some attempts I figured it out, but I couldn't find anything like this on SO, so I copy my solution here.

If I ran az `aks browse --help` I get the following indication

```
Command
    az aks browse : Show the dashboard for a Kubernetes cluster in a web browser.

Arguments
    --name -n           [Required] : Name of the managed cluster.
    --resource-group -g [Required] : Name of resource group. You can configure the default group
                                     using `az configure --defaults group=<name>`.
    --disable-browser              : Don't launch a web browser after establishing port-forwarding.
        Add this argument when launching a web browser manually, or for automated testing.
    --listen-address               : The listening address for the dashboard.  Default: 127.0.0.1.
        Add this argument to listen on a specific IP address.
    --listen-port                  : The listening port for the dashboard.  Default: 8001.
        Add this argument when the default listening port is used by another process or unavailable.

Global Arguments
    --debug                        : Increase logging verbosity to show all debug logs.
    --help -h                      : Show this help message and exit.
    --only-show-errors             : Only show errors, suppressing warnings.
    --output -o                    : Output format.  Allowed values: json, jsonc, none, table, tsv,
                                     yaml, yamlc.  Default: json.
    --query                        : JMESPath query string. See http://jmespath.org/ for more
                                     information and examples.
    --subscription                 : Name or ID of subscription. You can configure the default
                                     subscription using `az account set -s NAME_OR_ID`.
    --verbose                      : Increase logging verbosity. Use --debug for full debug logs.
```

That means that running my command with the extra parameter `--listen-port` makes the trick

```
az aks browse --resource-group my-resource-group --name aks-name-westeurope-001 --listen-port 10000
```